# How to set different protocol for each user (threads running) in gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to create a performance test suite where i have array of ID's that will be picked in random. For each ID , there is a designated auth_token assigned .

In the protocol , if i pass the method where the random ID's would take , it always sets it to that particular ID for the entire operation .

I am expecting something like , i am defining 10 virtual users and for each user the protocol should change the ID and continue the scenario execution .

Currently Gatling is setting the protocol at the first and uses the same protocol for all the 10 users.

````
        id = random.generate //generate random id
   authHeader = Method(id);

    def method (id:String) : String{
       if(id=="id1")
        return token1
       else if(id=="id2")
         return token2
       ""
}

    val httpProtocol = http.baseUrl(baseURI)
      .acceptHeader(header)
      .authorizationHeader(authHeader)
      .contentTypeHeader(contentType)
      .userAgentHeader(agentHeader)

val scn1: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("name")
        .exec(http("scenario1")
        .post(device_context) 
        .body(payload)
        .check(status.is(202)))

setUp(scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(2)).protocols(httpProtocol))```

In the above code i need the suite to run for 2 different id.
````

Comment: can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you're going to have to use a session variable to hold your authHeader. The DSL methods define builders that are only executed once - which explains what you're seeing.

The best way to do this would be to construct a feeder to hold your ids and auth tokens (I'm assuming you're not using the id anywhere else)

So define a feeder that maps a key (just a string) to a map that contains the id and auth token

```
//a list of strings to hold the auth tokens
private val ids = List(Map("id" -> "id1", "auth" -> "token1"), Map("id" -> "id2", "auth" -> "token2"), ...)

//the feeder to put a random token into the session
private val idFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("id" -> Random.shuffle(ids).head))
```

now when you call .feed on idFeeder you get a random Map that has keys for "id" and "auth" in the session variable "id"

so update your scenario to use the feeder and set an Authorization header (and remove .authorizationHeader from your protocol definition)

```
val scn1: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("name")
    .feed(idFeeder)
    .exec(http("scenario1")
    .header("Authorization", "${id.auth})"
    .post(device_context) 
    .body(payload)
    .check(status.is(202)))
```

in your body you can access the user id string with "${id.id}"

alternatively you could update your protocol definition to have the ${id} reference, but I find it nicer to have the feeder value used in the same block as the call to .feed

Comment: The prob here is i need to use the corresponding ID for the Token given by the feeder while constructing the payload for the body . 
Also i am not able to define header inside the ScenarioBuilder.It is throwing error.

Comment: then rather than have a map of string -> string for your feeder, you can have a map of string -> map(string -> string). I'll update the answer. (also fixed the header)

Comment: if there's a substantial list of users / auth tokens, it might be best to put them into a csv file and feed off that.

Comment: i need to pass "${id.auth}" to another method , where sequence of operations takes place. But when sent , the value of "${id.auth}" is not picked up . Instead , "${id.auth}" itself is passed as a string value to that method. Pls help!

Comment: i did that by using session. Thanks a lot for ur help